# Generating a map for point-like physics applications?

Tags: java

I'd like to generate a 3d map, which will then be used as a way to track and calculate various points (by using difference in position). This should be able to 'refresh' every frame or so.

What I am trying to achieve is basically a point-physics simulator.

What are my options in doing such things?

As I am providing no code, I expect no code, I just want a few ideas on how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Consider a 3d array with fixed coordinates, that makes things easy.

Comment: @SiKing "_...but if your question generally covers…_**a specific programming problem...** _then you’re in the right place to ask your question!_"

Comment: "What are my options in doing such things?" is not a question you would ask for a **specific problem**. Also you should show some research effort. Read about point-physics simulators and learn from that. The question you are asking has a thousand answers. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for how to ask.